# Is there any easy way to create new components in the Vue-cli?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vue-component, vue-cli

I can't find any easy way to create new components with the Vue-cli. I came from Angular and there I could just type `ng g c "component name"` and it would make the job.

Does anyone know about easy way to do it as with the angular cli?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that's not possible but it feels pretty redundant anyway as vue components contain so little boilerplate

Comment: Angular is a framework and it has an opinionated way to organize and define components. Vue is a presentation library with minimal boilerplate and you're free to define components however you like.

Comment: hmm im not so sure about that vue is a presentation library. in my opinion its a framework and it is mantioned in their website. anyway thanks for the comment. hope someone will be able to bring me some good news :).

Comment: Vue's tagline says _"progressive framework"_ meaning that it _"scales between a library and a full-featured framework."_

Comment: There are custom utility command like [vue-generate-component](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/vue-generate-component)

Comment: If you are using Vue's ide plugin "Vetur" you can scaffold. I think this is a better approach than generating through CLI.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess vue-cli doesn't have component creator command yet.
You can use [vue-generate-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-generate-component)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party, but I created a CLI called [Seabird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seabird) that will do this.

It will generate a component or view from an internal ejs file, or you can specify your own template and data object, and Seabird will compile it for you.

Comment: It's a shame you discontinued the project. Any chances you'll resume working on it?